# Plotting smoothspline

Tags: r

I fitted a curve to my plot using the smooth.spline() function.
Now I changed the x and y axis. That is the instead of plot(x,y)
I used plot(y,x) and than again I wanted to fit a curve using smooth.spline(y,x). The output is not really good. I wanted the previously fitted curve but the rotated one.

```
par(mar = c(0,2.5,0.2,0.))
smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(x=logBF[,2], y=times[timeindex],  spar=0.38)

plot(y=times[timeindex],x=logBF[,2],xlim=c(-4,ub1),
     xlab="",main="",ylab="", xaxt="n","l",lwd=4)
title(ylab= "time", line = 1.3,font.lab=2)

lines(smoothingSpline,  lty = "solid",lwd=1.5,col="gray80")
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I think you have to fit your spline on the original data (so `smooth.spline(x, y)`), and transform it before plotting: `lines(smoothingSpline$y, smoothingSpline$x)`. A spline on `(x, y)` is not the same as a rotated spline on `(y, x)`.

Comment: @Bas You are right. Many thanks Bas! It works well.